# Setting a nvarchar as a primary key for datatable relationships

Tags: sql

I have data table in the data base with the column`Email` set as `nvarchar(100)`(becuse i couldn't set it as a primary key when it was `nvarchar(MAX)`.
[image]

so it is primary key now, but i cant change it `Identity Specification` to yes, so I cant make a relationship with this table and another table when this is the primary key.
[image]

How can i make a relationship when this is as the primary key?

How can i set the `Identity Specification` to yes? or is there another way without doing it?

Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept of identity applies to an integer column.  The database will automatically assign an increasing number to each new row.  An identity column is typically a primary key.

So it makes no sense for a `varchar` column to be an identity column.  SSMS is right in graying the identity section out.

A foreign key can refer to any data type, including a `varchar(100)`.  A foreign key has to be indexed.  A column that is a primary key always has an index on it.

The foreign key column and the column it references must have the same data type.  Perhaps you could post the definition of the two tables you are trying to link.